# needs some help on using font-face on mobile webs

Tags: fonts, font-face

I have been seeking a way to implement an external font in to mobile webpages and I came across to this website.
http://www.google.com/fonts/earlyaccess

After some testings, we have found out that Android web browser downloads three "woff" fonts that are over 1m each including: Regular, Bold, and ExtraBold.
Although after the first download it caches, it still is too much to handle since it downloads all the fonts in the beginning.

I will be only needing Korean font. (some font files includ many different languages)
Is there an API to ONLY select Korean font and download that specific language that I need?

I came across to this project... https://code.google.com/p/sfntly/
If anyone has dealt with anything similar to this or knows about it, I would appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand your problem well but for fonts on the web try this converter:
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: so... basically I need an API or some sort to only pick out Korean language and download only Korean font. (for example... I download gothic font but I only need Korean gothic font, skipping other languages

Comment: Now it's clear, but unfortunately the website I just give doesn't have Korean subset natively as an option. If you want you can do it yourself by uploading font and selecting EXPERT... mode so you can type in subset yourself. The only problem is to figure out what subset of characters make complete Korean alphabet.